# get_user_pages() linux kernel using virt_to_page()

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

`get_user_pages()` implementation shows that it uses `virt_to_page()` to extract `struct page` pointer for given user space, page aligned virtual address.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/nommu.c#L171

`virt_to_page()` can only be used for directly mapped kernel addresses. How's that `get_user_pages()` is using the same for user space pages ?

Comment: This question is probably better answered in the Unix stack exchange.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at `nommu.c`, which is the implementation for hardware that does not have virtual memory. On those machines, there are no mappings.

The [real implementation in `memory.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c#L1693) uses the appropriate accesses for user-space pages.